# Can an item in gallery can be selected outside with the help of button?

Tags: powerapps

In my application, there is a gallery which has 6 categories. When I click on each category questions related to that category will be loaded in another gallery. After completion of one category the next category needs to be selected. So, when I click on next button can I select the 2nd category present in that category_gallery?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by changing a variable that is bound to the Default property of the gallery. If your data source has an index:

```
ClearCollect(
    categories,
    { Id: 1, Name: "Category 1" },
    { Id: 2, Name: "Category 2" },
    { Id: 3, Name: "Category 3" },
    { Id: 4, Name: "Category 4" },
    { Id: 5, Name: "Category 5" },
    { Id: 6, Name: "Category 6" })
```

You can set the default category in a place such as the OnVisible property of the screen:

```
Set(defaultCategory, LookUp(categories, Id = 1))
```

Then, in the button outside the gallery, you can update the value of the defaultCategory variable to move to the next item:

```
If(
    Gallery1.Selected.Id < CountRows(categories),
    Set(defaultCategory, LookUp(categories, Id = (Gallery1.Selected.Id + 1))); Reset(Gallery1))
```

The screen capture below shows this expression being used:

[image]
Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried the thing which you have explained, but I'm not able to navigate to next category when I click on Next Button.

Can u explain me where did you give your collection.

Comment: The collection (`categories`) is created on the OnStart of the app, with the ClearCollect expression shown in the beginning of the answer. And the Items property of the gallery is set to that collection.